# Exception handling in TPL

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using the following code for creating some files.

I have observed that sometimes if some exception occurs all Parallel.For threads stop in between.

I have few questions.

1. Should I be using AggregateException in CreateReport method or its @ rt place.
2. How to make sure that if exceptions arises in any of the threads it does not stop other parallel threads.

```
    Try
            dtScheduledReports = objReprotHelper.GetTopImmediateReportsForExecution()

        Parallel.For(0, dtScheduledReports.Rows.Count, Sub(i)
                                                           CreateReport(dtScheduledReports.Rows(i))
                                                       End Sub)
    Catch ae As AggregateException
        For Each ex As Exception In ae.InnerExceptions
            ExceptionHandler.LogError(ex)
        Next
    End Try

Private Sub CreateReport(dtRow As DataRow, scheduleType As Integer)
        Try
              //do something
        Catch 
              throw
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think that they stop?

Comment: I maintain status of each report in DB i.e progress checks like start, end. Some never reach end.

Comment: What does CreateReport do? Does it access to the DB?

Comment: yes, it does. Gets the required info from DB and creates csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ConcurrentQueue(Of Exception)` to enable safe exception enqueueing from multiple threads. This allows to execute the entire loop and throws all exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

```
Private Sub DoAParalelJobAndThrowErrors

  Dim exQueue as New ConcurrentQueue(Of Exception)
  dtScheduledReports = objReprotHelper.GetTopImmediateReportsForExecution()
  // Execute the complete loop and capture all exceptions.
  Parallel.For(0, dtScheduledReports.Rows.Count, Sub(i)
                                                       Try
                                                         CreateReport(dtScheduledReports.Rows(i))
                                                       Catch ex as Exception
                                                         exQueue.Enqueue(ex)
                                                       End Try
                                                     End Sub)

  If exQueue.count > 0 throw new AggregateException(exQueue)

End Sub

Private Sub CreateReport(dtRow As DataRow, scheduleType As Integer)       
    //do something
End Sub
```

According MSDN this way doen't break the loop, all rows should be processed.

Comment: thanks for the reply but should not I just add a try catch inside CreateReport and in this way it will only break the current execution and not the entire loop.

Comment: It is a bad idea do a catch to ignore a exception. And if you use the concurrentQueue in CreateReport you are adding a ugly dependency. What if CreateReport is called from other place that is not parallel? Why it has to be aware about concurrenQueue? Let createReport be a standard action with standard exception handling (let the exception bubble in the stack in this case) and put special exception handling in yor special method (parallel for).